# What is the correct way to silently close InputStream in finally block without losing the original exception?

Tags: java

I am wondering if the below code closes InputStream in finally block correctly

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test");
try {
    for(;;) {
        int b = is.read();
        ...
    }
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
    }
}
```

If an exception happens during is.read() will be it ignored / suppressed if an exception happens during is.close()?

Comment: can't you catch the exception and handle it before the finally?

Comment: See the following two links on the same https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ClosingResourcesExplained and https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1118 and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception from is.close() will be suppressed and the exception from is.read() will be the one that propagates up.

Comment: True, but only if the exception from `is.close()` is an IO exception.

Comment: often it is a NullpointerException, when chaining streams, and the first stream throws a FileNotFpundException

Comment: @Alex In the example given, `is` cannot be null at the `is.close` call,  because otherwise the constructor of FileInputStream will have throw an exception earlier like you stated. However that is outside of the exception block. I can only reply to the code as it is shown not code as we'd write it ourselves!

@Etienne you are correct and in this example they both throw the same exception.

Comment: @Etienne interesting observation, but then it can only be a RuntimeException (programming errors) which are not supposed to be caught

Answer (score 17):

Best way is to use Java 7 and use try with resources, or do same thing manualy and add exception from closing as suppressed exception.

Pre Java 7:
If you are throwing your custom exception, you can add in it supressed exception like it is done in Java 7 (in your exception create fields List suppressed and put there exceptions from close operation and when dealing with your exception, look there too.
If you cannot do that, I don't know anything better than just log it.

examples:
from [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

but better form is:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

This way even if creation of FileReader is succesfull but creation of BufferedReader fails (eg not enough memory), FileReader will be closed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. For those who haven't understood, lookup http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html

Answer (score 15):

You can close it with IOUtils from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

```
public void readStream(InputStream ins) {
    try {
        //do some operation with stream         
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(ins);
    }
}
```

Comment: DON'T USE, deprecated and removed without replacement on IOUtils 2.6. "Please use the try-with-resources statement or handle suppressed exceptions manually."

Answer (score 8):

The [Java 6 specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.20.2) say

> If execution of the try block completes abruptly for any other reason R, then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>   If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.
>   If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

So you are right, you will lose the original exception.

The solution probably is to write your finally block so defensively that it is a bigger surprise (worth propagating) if the finally block fails than if an exception comes out of the try catch block.

So, for example, if it is possible that the stream may be null when you try to close it, check it:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test");
try {
    for(;;) {
        int b = is.read();
        ...
    }
} finally {
    try {
        if( is!=null ) {
            is.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
    }
}
```

In Java 7, Alpedar's solution is the way to go of course.

Comment: is = null is impossible, new FileInputStream("test") cannot return null

Comment: It's meant to be a simple example, and it'd depend on what happens in the  `...`. Was looking for a runtime exception that may get thrown in the finally block cause that's when things get interesting.

Answer (score 2):

With the code you posted:

- If `is.close()` throws an `IOException`, it gets discarded and the original exception propagates.
- If `is.close()` throws something else (a `RuntimeException` or an `Error`), it propagates and the original exception is discarded.

With Java 7, the correct way to close an InputStream without loosing the original exception is to use a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html):

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test")) {
    for(;;) {
        int b = is.read();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Prior to Java 7, what you do is just fine, except you may want to catch all exceptions instead of just `IOException`s.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code sample if an exception occurs at the `int b = is.read();` point, then the exception will be raised higher up the call chain.

Note though that the finally block will still execute and if the `Inputstream` invalid another exception will be thrown, but this exception will be "swallowed", which may be acceptable depending on your use case.

Edit:

Based on the title of your question, I would add that what you have is fine in my opinion.  You may want to additionally add a `catch` block to explicitly handle (or perhaps wrap) any exception within the first `try` block, but it is also acceptable to let any IO exceptions raise up - this really depends on your API.  It may or may not be acceptable to let IO exceptions raise up. If it is, then what you have it fine - if it isn't then you may want to handle/wrap the IO exception with something more suitable to your program.

Comment: The exception will not be swallowed, it will be propagated instead of the original exception.

Comment: If `InputStream` is `null`, then the code will raise an NPE that hides the original exception, but if the `close()` raises an IO exception, then that exception will be discarded and the original one will propagate.

Comment: @EtienneMiret agreed, it will. But the answer says the NPE will get swallowed, which it won't.

Comment: is = null is impossible, new FileInputStream("test") cannot return null.

Answer (score 0):

How about the next solution:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test");
Exception foundException=null;
try {
    for(;;) {
        int b = is.read();
        ...
    }
} catch (Exception e){
  foundException=e;
}
finally {
    if(is!=null)
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
    }
}
//handle foundException here if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

> If an exception happens during is.read() will be it ignored / suppressed if an exception happens during is.close()?

Yes. You have a catch block for the exception in close() which does not re-throw the exception. Ergo  it is not propagated or rethrown.

Comment: try { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); } finally {try { throw new IllegalStateException();} catch (Exception e2) {}} -- IllegalArgumentException is thrown

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev What on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample to help to understand your problem,
if you declare the scanner in the try-catch block it will give compiler warning the resource is not closed.
so either make it locally or just in try()

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScanInt {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type an integer in the console: ");

    try (Scanner consoleScanner = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        System.out.println("You typed the integer value: "
                + consoleScanner.nextInt());

    } catch (InputMismatchException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
        System.out.println("Catch Bowled");
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    System.out.println("----------------");
}
}
```